# Visualize data in microsecond resolution

Tags: python, data-visualization, influxdb, grafana, chronograf

I'm measuring multiple processes in a component to see where bottlenecks are. These processes take anything from 1-1000us to complete.
I'm logging this in an influxDB database, set to us resolution, using Python3.

My problem is visualising this. I tried grafana thinking it would suit me. However,  when graphing this microsecond data it will show multiple datapoints on 1 ms, the max grafana supports, making it impossible to see increments or zoom in or anything similar.

Judging by some google results, [1,](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3035) [2,](https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/issues/1449) [3,](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/5812) I'm not alone.

Is there any way I can make this data more readable/understandable by either having the graphing tool display it in microseconds or be able to change the X-axis to something different than a timestamp. (Ideally something in similar to grafana or chronograf.)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Not really in the way I wanted but I used a different panel that allowed me to use something different than the timestamp as X-axis (I forgot the name). So instead of timestamp on X I used the timestamp of the process (starts at 0 us and increments). That worked okay but wasn't as pretty or neat as the normal graphs. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Grafana feature request post (from 2016):

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6252

Quote by Torkel Ödegaard, Co-founder of Grafana:

> No there is no way to do that. It would be quite tricky as all time
>   formats in javascript (and time libs) only go down to millisecond resolution.

As it seems this is currently not possible (even not in the mid-term future) as Javascript supports only milliseconds